# Alias to hide chrome history

Tags: bash, google-chrome

I'm looking for some kind of bash alias or script or something that can put my web browsers in a kind of "Guest" mode. So that all my history, favorites, reading list...etc is hidden.

I mostly just wan't to have a safe mode for my pc when I'm doing presentations and whatnot lol.

edit : I'm on mac if that helps

Answer (score 0):

just use incognito window in chrome,
your history will not trace

press ctrl+shif+n when you already open chrome

Comment: I like to keep a list of favorite websites that tend to appear in the search bar whenever you start typing. I really don't want these showing up lol. Any way to fix that?

Comment: It's Ctrl + Shift + N, not B.

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome use
    google-chrome --temp-profile